# Need XOR ascii message to print to screen

Tags: python, xor, brute-force

I've researched this topic for the last two days and have tried multiple ways of trying to solve this issue I am having with my program. This program is suppose to take a 16 bit random key and XOR it with a message typed in by the user. There is currently no errors in my program but I'm having on issue.

```
import string
import random

message = raw_input("Enter your message: ").split(",")
size = 2    # or whatever lenght you want your random string to be
allowed = string.ascii_letters # add any other allowed characters here
randomstring = ''.join([allowed[random.randint(0, len(allowed) - 1)] for x in xrange(size)])

print
print("This is the key used for encryption:")
print randomstring #prints out key used
print
print("APPLYING XOR METHOD TO MESSAGE AND KEY")
print("--------------------------------------")

for i in xrange(0,len(message)-1):
    l += [ord(message) ^ ord(randomstring) for message,randomstring in zip(message,randomstring)]
print l

print

#BRUTE FORCE TO FIND OUT RANDOMSTRING
key= []
count =0
while(key!=randomstring):
    key = ''.join([allowed[random.randint(0, len(allowed) - 1)] for x in xrange(size)])
    count = count + 1
    if(key==randomstring):
        print ("FOUND KEY USED BY BRUTE FORCE: "+key)
        print (count)
        break
```

This code generates the random key and find out the same key after the for loops finishes. For example my output would be,

```
Enter your message: hi

This is the key used for encryption:
ng

APPLYING XOR METHOD TO MESSAGE AND KEY
--------------------------------------

FOUND KEY USED BY BRUTE FORCE: ng
1052
```

I need a way to print the encrypted XOR message to the screen.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Uhh, what is your question?

Comment: I need a way to print the encrypted XOR message to the screen

Comment: Is `l` the encrypted message? What happens if you just do `print l`?

Comment: Where is `l` created?

Comment: If i add     print l    in the for loop, it skips over it and leaves it blank.

Comment: "*There is currently no errors in my program*" - I disagree. Enter "Hello, world, today" as your input string and see what happens.

Comment: okay i see what happens now, @Robᵩ Thanks! I'll post what I find out. I was able to fix that issue, but now I can't get my key to print out for the last part of the program.
output: 'Enter your message: hello, world

This is the key used for encryption:
KcgiIyDTeZs

APPLYING XOR METHOD TO MESSAGE AND KEY
--------------------------------------
[35, 6, 11, 5, 38, 85, 100, 35, 10, 40, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31]
'

Comment: Yeah, it hangs for me, too. I didn't bother to debug the decoder code -- that really wasn't your question.

Comment: That is okay , I just had to figure out this problem. I really do appreciate this help. I just get that repeated number now. i'll debug it and post what I find out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, fix your call to `raw_input`:

```
message = raw_input("Enter your message: ")
```

When you called `.strip(",")` on your input string, you created a list of strings. So, if you had originally entered "Hello, world", the result would have been `['Hello', ' world']`.

Later in your program you require `message` to be a string, not a list.

Next, initialize the variable `l` and print its value after the loop:

```
l=[]
for i in xrange(0,len(message)-1):
    l += [ord(message) ^ ord(randomstring) for message,randomstring in zip(message,randomstring)]
print l
```